# pass img src path to php function through javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { 
    $('.LSide img').click(function() { 
      $('.BigImage img').attr("src", $(this).attr("src")); 
      var img =$('.BigImage img').attr("src").slice(0,-5); 
      //alert($('.BigImage img').attr("src").slice(0,-5)) 
      //alert(img); 
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

I want to pass that var img variable to php function, and call that php function at the click event. does it possible?

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: are you talking about load image on the fly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AJAX call to your PHP script and pass the value of `img` with that call.

What you can't do is mix Javascript code (which is a client side scripting language) and PHP code (which is a server side scripting language)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can do that by sending a POST request, and with AJAX it'd be:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { img: img.serialize() }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

```
In your html file. Call click finction like this:
<img src="a.png" id="BigImage" onclick="click()">

<script type="text/javascript">
function click(){
    var a = document.getElementById('BigImage').src; //id of your img tag
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'b.php',
        data: { ch : a },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
           }
    });
}
</script>

In your b.php file use `$_POST['ch']` as you want
    <?php
       echo $_POST['ch'];
    ?>
```